# How can I add a button to the native Android call info screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I'd like to add a button to this native Android view:

[image]

I've seen a solution for [drawing on top of all apps](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) via the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission, but what if I only want to draw on top of this specific window? Does Android even allow such a thing?

Comment: THere is no built in ability to do that.  You'd need to request SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW and then figure out somewhow when this window is shown.  Also note that not all phones use the same dialer (OEMs can switch it out, for that matter so can users), so do not expect all phones to use this screen.

Comment: Realistically speaking, this is the kind of thing you can do if you are building Android from source, or if you have a rooted device where you can modify system apps, and feel like using reverse engineering tools to put some extra code into an app without actually rebuilding it (and all of its dependencies) from source.  It's not really in the territory of ordinary 3rd party app development (as is most often, *but not exclusively* covered here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a button, or any other views, to an activity in another application. That would be a terrible security issue as malicious apps would be able to mimic other apps and hijack user actions etc. Just imagine putting your own password field on top of some other app's login activity, that would mean you could steal the entered password.

If you still claim to have a valid use case please elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve, so that perhaps you can be guided in the right direction.

Comment: My use case is that I think it would be really convenient to have a button on that screen that just does a google search for the phone number. Currently if you get a call from an unknown number there's no simple way to accomplish this - you can't even copy it to the clipboard, you have to either "Copy to dialing screen" or "Send Message". I figured a small app that could draw over the activity would be the easiest way to accomplish this, but I can certainly understand why Android locks this down.

Comment: Well you could react to an incoming call and display something at that point, such as a dialog or notification in the status bar. Several automated caller ID apps do that. But to trigger your ui to be launched at a later time  when a certain activity of another app is being displayed, and to follow the life cycle of said activity, is another story. Of course another albeit strange option would be to have your app implement the send message intent so that it pops up in a chooser when user clicks send message button...